# Which esteimator is used to compute cumulative incidence curves in R with the "tidycmprsk" package? Is it the Aalen-Johansen estimator?

Tags: survival-analysis, survival, cumulative-distribution-function

I am using R with the "tidycmprsk" package to compute cumulative incidence curves with competing risk (death of disease and death from other cause) for my research project. Is it the Aalen-Johansen estimator which is used for estimating/plotting cumulative incidence curves by tidycmprsk or another estimator? I would like to write what estimator I have used in my manuscript methods section.

My code is :

```
cuminc(Surv(m_surv_5year,DSS_5year)~mutation, data=LBCL) %>%
ggcuminc(outcome=c("1","2"))+
labs(x="Months")+
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,12,24,36,48,60))+
scale_linetype_manual(values = c('solid', 'dashed'),labels = c('Death of disease', 'Death of other cause')) +
add_censor_mark()+
add_pvalue()+
add_risktable(risktable_stats = c("n.risk"))
```

I have looked in the package description in R and on github, but was not able to find the answer.